# Why doesn't hitTest(_:with:) interact with programmatically added UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm having trouble getting **hitTest(_:with:)** to traverse a UIImageView when it's added programmatically.

In IB I make a square area and give it a tag of 1. Within that square I insert a UIImageView (tag=2) (orange/white in screenshot below). In the ViewController I programmatically create another square(tag=3). Then add a UIImageView(tag=4) within that (red/green in screenshot below). The following picture shows this:

[image: IB and programmatic embedded UIImageViews]

I'm using **touchesBegan(_:with:)** to perform hitTest. When I touch the orange I get a printout of a view with tag 1 (expected). If I touch the white square I get printout with tag 2 (expected). These were created in IB.

When I touch the red square I get tag 3 (expected). When I touch green I get tag 3! (NOT expected). I've looked at the runtime hierarchy and don't see any difference in structure between IB & programmatic. It appears that **hitTest(_:with:)** doesn't recognize/traverse/include/detect the programmatic UIImageView. What's the difference?

Here's my ViewController code:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet var gameView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet var boardView: UIImageView!

  var g2 : UIView!
  var b2 : UIImageView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    g2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 50, width: 240, height: 240))
    g2.backgroundColor = .red
    g2.tag = 3
    view.addSubview(g2)

    b2 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 75, y: 75, width: 80, height: 80))
    b2.backgroundColor = .green
    b2.tag = 4
    g2.addSubview(b2)
  }

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if event!.type != .touches { return }

    if let first = touches.first {
      let loc = first.location(in: view)
      if let v = view.hitTest(loc, with: nil) {
        print("\(v)")
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I've changed the programmatic UIImageView to a UIView and that IS detected by hitTest as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIImageView` has `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to `false` by default, e.g. it doesn't receive any touches.

This should be true for a storyboard too, probably you have enabled `User Interactions Enabled` checkmark.

Most of other views have this property set to `true` by default, but if you wanna interact with `UIImageView` touches, you need to enable it explicitly.

```
b2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```